# return value in method ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have this method:

```
def validates_image_dependents
  post = self.find(params[:id])
   i=0
   for this_post in Post.all
    if this_post.posted_filename == post.post_filename
     i+=1
    end
   end
 return i > 1
end
```

I want the method return true or false dependend if i > 1, but I get nil.

What am I doing bad?

Without method works fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you see `nil` result in the irb output like this:

```
irb(main):018:0> def validates_image_dependents                                                                 
irb(main):019:1>   post = self.find(params[:id])                                                                
irb(main):020:1>    i=0                                                                                         
irb(main):021:1>    for this_post in Post.all                                                                   
irb(main):022:2>     if this_post.posted_filename == post.post_filename                                         
irb(main):023:3>      i+=1                                                                                      
irb(main):024:3>     end                                                                                        
irb(main):025:2>    end                                                                                         
irb(main):026:1>  return i > 1                                                                                  
irb(main):027:1> end                                                                                            
=> nil
```

This happens because you *defined method* `validates_image_dependents` and *definition of method expression* returned `nil`.

You need to execute your method to get actual result:

```
irb(main):028:0> validates_image_dependents 
=> true
```

Comment: Perfect, this was problem :D Sorry sorry for my inability.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. It returns true or false.

```
def some_method
   i=4 #or i = 0
   return i > 1
end
```

May be something weird happening in the method? I'd put a debugger and check.

Comment: With this method I get **nil** in my console rails. I use ruby 1.9.2-p290. I use Rails 3.1.3

Comment: Mine was in ruby ree-1.8.7-2011.03. I will try it in ruby 1.9.2 and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

to simplify your method you can use something like this:

```
  Post.all.count(|t| t.posted_filename == post.filename) > 1
```

I can't see any ways that this code returns nil.

`return i > 1` cannot return nil no matter which type or value i has. 
If i is nil or any other type rather than Numeric it should raise an error, otherwise, it should return a boolean value. Take a better look on what code you're running.

Comment: The problem is that I have run the method, then return true or false :D.